# Xamarin Android FrameLayout change view

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, layout-inflater, android-framelayout, fragmentmanager

I'm trying to execute the following code:

```
FrameLayout fragmentContainer = FindViewById<FrameLayout>(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer);
fragmentContainer.RemoveAllViews();
fragmentMain.view = fragmentMain.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MainLayoutPortrait, null, false);
fragmentContainer.AddView(fragmentMain.view);
```

But when I'm getting to the 3d line of my code and trying to get fragmentMain.LayoutInflater:

```
fragmentMain.view = fragmentMain.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MainLayoutPortrait, null, false);
```

the program fail with error:

```
onGetLayoutInflater() cannot be executed until the Fragment is attached to the FragmentManager.
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do here ?

Comment: I have a framelayout and I want to inflate a right view depending on portrait or landscape orientation when user press the "back" button

Comment: Hi, @НиколайМартынюк, can you show the code about `fragmentMain..View` and `onGetLayoutInflater()`?

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT https://prnt.sc/iwwqm1

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this :

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
        view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Buttons, layout);
```

Incase you are in fragment use activity context to get GetSystemService

Goodluck!